# Jmeter - Parallel execution of HTTP request after Login

Tags: jmeter

Scenario

- Navigating to a login page which generates session data key which will be used while entering the credentials for login
- Entering credentials along with sessiondataKey(i.e. sessiondatakey is a entered as parameter in Jmeter Http Header )
- Login mechanism provides authorization token

  - Once authorization token is extracted from response ,initialization request is triggered
- As this a XHR enabled site - multiple requests are triggered all together at same time to API's once response from initialization service is received (Note - Here in every request authorization token which we got previously is sent as a part of Header)

Question - What should be My Test Plan structure in jmeter where I would like to login with 50 Users (Data referred from CSV datset)  - Once Login - Initialization done then fire up all request together.

Answer (score 0):

Just go for [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md), your test plan should look like:

- Login
- Parallel Controller

  - Request 1
  - Request 2
  - Request 3
  - etc.

So `Request 1`, `Request 2`, etc. will be executed at the same time, each with its own thread.

See [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter) article for comprehensive information if needed.

You can install Parallel Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image: JMeter Plugins Parallel Controller]